# NSDrawNinePartImage gaps

Tags: cocoa, drawing, appkit

I am working on drawing custom buttons/textfields with `NSDrawNinePartImage`. I slice up an image into nine parts in code and draw it into a rect with `NSDrawNinePartImage`.

Unfortunately I am getting some gaps in the drawing pattern. I thought it had something to do with my slicing code, but I saved them out as images from where I slice them, and they all look good (I even put them together and they looked good). Some of the cases where I use it to work just fine though despite some using the same images.

I am pretty confident that it comes down to the actual drawing.

Do you know of any `NSGraphicsContext` or other settings that would affect it or something else that may be causing this?

With gaps

[image: With gaps]

Without gaps

[image: Without gaps]

Comment: I've noticed the same thing in one of my projects. I've saved the images and drew them with NSDrawNinePartImage in a new project, and they draw fine. When I draw them in my custom button however, they have gaps.

Comment: Are you sure you're drawing on pixel boundaries? In the first image, it looks like there's some sub-pixel rendering that I can't see in the second image.

Comment: Since my answer was deleted, I'll answer your follow-up question here. Where you draw your nine part, use `-[NSView convertRect:toView:nil]` on the frame you pass to `NSDrawNinePartImage` and print out the result. If there are any non-integral values, then that might be the cause of your problem. Use something like `-[NSView centerScanRect:]` to ensure the rect is only pixel boundaries.

Comment: @kperryua I tried that it improved it slightly but there are still gaps

Comment: Are your slices also integral-sized?

Answer (score 4):

I fixed a similar issue by disable the anti-alias option

```
NSGraphicsContext* theContext = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
[theContext saveGraphicsState];
[theContext setShouldAntialias: NO];
NSDrawNinePartImage(...);
[theContext restoreGraphicsState];
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that your upper left and lower right images are a pixel too wide?

> This function uses the top-left and bottom-right corner images to
>   determine the widths and heights of the edge areas that need to be
>   filled. If the width or height of the bottom-left and top-right images
>   are not sized appropriately, they may be scaled to fill their corner
>   area. Edge areas between the corners are tiled using the corresponding
>   image. Similarly, the center area is tiled using the specified center
>   image.

Answer (score 0):

Use even sizes in images.  I did this, and it solved this problem for me.